Changing multiple traffic policies at once in Route 53
I have dozens of traffic policies, each configured with a handful versions. From time to time I need to switch from a specific set of versions to another.
Is there a way to construct some sort of a profile to group these sets of traffic policy versions together, or do I have to resort to the REST API?
